# What is needed to get a business on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-my-business

Two days ago I registered a shop on Google Business.

It did not yet appear on Google Maps.

A 2012 page:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-mapmaker/ykYOPA5oGTE

says that a reviewer or more should accept it.

Some other people told me that Google sends a postal letter with a verification code in it, but that was in 2016.

What is the state of the art on this? What Google expects from us to register a shop on their map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google sends a post card for verification which will be available in the provided address within 2-7 working days.

But if you are marking a part of existing building, Google asks Local guides to check the facts. It'll show the locations to local guides and if they mark it as existing location it'll appear asap in Google maps.

Comment: Is there an interface to ask about this if nothing happens for too long?

Comment: In most cases these type of discussion is in google forums where you can find lot of experienced person.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention your business services, opening closing time, business address...after applying for the google business listing, google will send you the verification code and after that your business listing will be activated and you can see your business on google left side of google search bar.

Comment: I did give these data and got a verification code through cell phone. Still, the shop is not in Google Maps